# Scanning for altbeacons with specific manufacturer code

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am attempting to intermittently scan for nearby beacons and store off every received beacon with a particular manufacturer code.  How do I use the altbeacon Library to start and stop scanning for altbeacons with a specific manufacturer code and store off every received beacon during each scan?  I would like for the scanner to scan for 20 seconds every 5 minutes after the activity has been created.
@davidgyoung

Answer (score 0):

For the manufacturer code 268 (hex 0x0112), you can match this with the following BeaconParser setup code:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setLayout("m:0-3=1201beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

Note that in the layout string, the two hex bytes of the manufacturer code are put as the first part of the "matching" m expression m:0-3=1201beac.  They are in reverse "little endian" order because this is how they appear in the packet.  So 0x0112 becomes m:0-3=1201.  Similarly if you were using radius networks 0x0118 company code, you would use m:0-3=1801.

The regular ranging APIs will return you a list of all beacons that match this.  To scan for 20 seconds out of every 5 minutes, simply use:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(20000l); // 20,000 ms
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(280000l);// 280,000 ms + 20,000 ms = 5 minutes
```